# Is there a way to configure an external SSO login system with my existing Django Web Application

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on

I have a django application with a default login configured. I also have an external SSO login system. Need to configure the django application so that it can use the SSO and login to the application.

Comment: are you looking for social-sites-login ?

Comment: no, im looking for single-sign-on. Like, in my organisation, if i login to this SSO system, it will automatically log me in to all the applications i want to use. Similarly i want to enable this in my django application.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) tool allows you to sync your mobile app with web app. You can easily manage your application users as an administrator.